# What does $(''class for the same element', element) mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't unterstand this syntax:

```
var dir = $("a.store").parents("table")[0];
var stores = $("a.store:has(b)", dir);
```

What will `store` contain?

What is the meaning of `"$("a.store:has(b)", dir);"`?

Comment: jQuery has documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 3):

It will return a collection of dom elements that match the css selector ("a.store:has(b)") that are children of the dom element stored in the 'dir' variable.

Comment: To be more precise: *descendants*, not only children.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `dir` is the *context* of the selector. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) linked by Felix in his comment:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:
>
> ```
> $('div.foo').click(function() {
>   $('span', this).addClass('bar');
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From the jquery docs,

:has() Selector

> Selects elements which contain at
>   least one element that matches the
>   specified selector.
>
> The expression $('div:has(p)') matches
>   a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere among
>   its descendants, not just as a direct
>   child.

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Regarding the second parameter to jQuery, it is the context. It can be a DOM element on which the selector operates.

In your case:
var dir will have a `table` which is parent of `<a class="store" ...`

the store variable will contain only those `<a class="store" ..` which have a `<b>` inside them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.store")
```

Will get all `<a>` elements that have the class `.store`

```
.parents("table")[0];
```

Will get the table(s) these `<a>` reside in.

```
$("a.store:has(b)", dir);
```

Will find all `<a>` elements that have the class `.store` and contain a `<b>` element, using the previously found tables `dir` as context, meaning that instead of going through the entire document to find matches, it will only go through these tables.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form..

Its equivalent to doing..

```
$('someParent').find('.matchingDescendants');
```